# supportsLollipop in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am learning `Kotlin` syntac and extensions of it. I came across that if you want to run code on Lollipop and above you can do

```
supportsLollipop {
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK)
}
```

This seems well, I am trying to use it in my code but getting an error "Expecting member declaration" .

[image]

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        submitButton.setOnClickListener({ view ->
            longToast("Clicked")
        })
    }

    inline fun supportsLollipop(code: () -> Unit) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            code()
        }
    }

    supportsLollipop {
        Log.d("Test", "Test")
    }
}
```

Do I need to install any extension for it ? Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Can you paste your code as opposed to screenshot

Comment: @ArunShankar see it now

Comment: I have updated my answer for it to work with your code. The problem is that method invocation cannot be at top level

Comment: @RaunakVerma https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/

Comment: @Williams thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go through https://android.jlelse.eu/keddit-part-7-infinite-scroll-higher-order-functions-lambdas-3a11fbd5090e

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        submitButton.setOnClickListener({ view ->
            longToast("Clicked")
        })

        supportsLollipop {
            Log.d("Test", "Test")
        }
    }

    inline fun supportsLollipop(code: () -> Unit) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            code()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have similar kinda in my code, see my updated question

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the function.

```
 fun supportsLollipop(code: () -> Unit) {
        supportsVersion(code, 21)
    }

private fun supportsVersion(code: () -> Unit, sdk: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= sdk) {
        code.invoke()
    }
}
```